# NetBeans. Удалённое развёртывание на GlassFish 4.1

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, развертывание

Я пытался развернуть NetBeans проект на удалённом GlassFish v4.1, но процесс развёртывания начинается, и ничего не происходит.

1. В логи ничего не пишется
2. GlassFish v3.1.2.2 отлично работает (на том же хосте)
3. Развёртывание с Http DAS работает отлично
4. Развёртывание на локальном GlassFish v4.1 работает отлично

Как развернуть NetBeans проект на удалённом GlassFish v4.1?

Comment: Questions in English -> http://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Это же ресский сайт.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он на английском.

Comment: @Qwertiy больше всего меня удивило _Barnail, Altay_ в профиле _Kornikal_. Если это _Барнаул, Алтай_, то как человек из России на русском SO (отличие от оригинального SO хорошо ведь видно в интерфейсе сайта) умудрился задать вопрос на английском?

Comment: @Regent, учитывая качество английского, я не удивлюсь, если человек из России. Но вот зачем задавать вопрос на английском??

Comment: @Kornikal Рекомендую оформить этот комментарий в виде ответа на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сайте с загрузкой GF4.1 
 https://glassfish.java.net/download.html 
 лежит архив со старой версией grizzly, поэтому удаленное развертывание не работает и нет никаких логов. 
 **Чтобы исправить нужно заменить jar-файл в папке glassfish/modules на доступный по ссылке**
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7319744/glassfish-4.1/nucleus-grizzly-all.jar